# How to handle corrupt namespace in journaled MongoDB instance?

Tags: mongodb, corruption

I've found that my MongoDB instance has a corruption problem. The [`validate` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/validate/) returns:

```
{ 

    ...stuff...

    "advice" : "ns corrupt, requires repair",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I think this may be a corrupt index, but I can't figure out which index. The collection is very large, so reindexing is not ideal.

I would try [`repairDatabase`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) but it's [not recommended for journaled instances](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/); mine is definitely journaled (checked with [`serverStatus`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/)).

> **Note:** When using journaling, there is almost never any need to run repairDatabase. In the event of an unclean shutdown, the server will be able restore the data files to a pristine state automatically.

Short of rebuilding all indexes (which may or may not fix the corruption), what can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did seem to be a corrupt index.  Running [`reIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/reIndex/) seems to have fixed the problem.